# Installing Mercurial from Source Files on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mercurial, installation

I am new to Ubuntu and Mercurial, so I wanted to see if anyone has experience installing Mercurial from source since it does not have an Ubuntu-specific distribution.

What is the best way for me to install Mercurial from source? Any ideas? :)

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: In the future, tell us what version of Ubuntu you're using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it does.  It's called [mercurial](http://packages.ubuntu.com/karmic/mercurial).  You can do:

```
sudo apt-get install mercurial
```

or use the graphical [package manager](https://help.ubuntu.com/8.04/add-applications/C/add-applications-introduction.html).

If you need a later version, you can use the [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~mercurial-ppa/+archive/releases).  You certainly can build it from source if you want.  The easiest way is to use `apt-get source`, then build the package.  If you want to build it from upstream source, that's possible too.

Comment: As much as the above will correctly install the mercurial binaries this doesn't really provide the best answer to the actual question.  
  
Whereas following these instructions does: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mercurial

Comment: Does not install latest version on Ubuntu and the alternative PPA is also out of date.

Answer (score 9):

You can install Mercurial from source using `pip` (`apt-get install pip` if you don't already have it):

```
pip install mercurial
```

This will usually install it to `/usr/local/bin/hg`, instead of the default `/usr/bin/hg`.

If you want to install a specific version, you can always point `pip` at one of the [source releases](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/release/), such as https://www.mercurial-scm.org/release/mercurial-1.8.1.tar.gz.

Lastly, if you *really* want to install from source, download one of those source tarballs, unzip it, and run

```
cd mercurial-1.8.1
python setup.py install
```

Comment: I think the command is `sudo apt-get install python-pip` and NOT `sudo apt-get install pip`

Comment: And this is the command to install source archive file using PIP: `pip install /path/to/source.tar.gz` or `pip install http://example.com/source.tar.gz`

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu/Debian:  `sudo apt-get install mercurial`

Comment: Does not install latest version on Ubuntu.